# Wordpress ultimate member edit search filters for custom fields

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to edit search filters on Wordpress plugin ultimate member? As I know standard filters include the only field which is selected from backend and search user must match all specified fields (logical and). I want some way to edit search and add more functions (or, less than, more than) for some fields. So far I haven't found out how the search is proposed if is based on the global $wpdb variable or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ajax in my example to search for users based on conditions, and here I use country, The list of cities is already defined in an array, and I summon it here in loop.

```
<?php /*Template Name: Users* /?> 


<div class="row">
        <div class="col mb-2">
            <h5 class="mb-3" >
                <?php echo __('Advanced','booksinfo') ?>
            </h5>
            
            <input class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="<?php echo __('User name','booksinfo') ?>" name="username" id="username" onkeyup="users_fetch()"  />
                            
            <select name="usercountry" id="usercountry" class="form-control" onchange="users_fetch()">
                <option value="all" ><?php echo __('All countries','booksinfo') ?></option>
                <?php
                    $user_country = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'user_registration_user_country', true );


                        foreach ($countrys_list as $country ) {
                            
                            echo "<option value=\"$country\">".esc_html__($country,'booksinfo') ."</option>";
                        
                    }
                    ?>
            </select>
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row" id="users_list_div">
                <script>
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: { action: 'users_data_fetch'},
                        success: function(data) {
                            jQuery('#users_list_div').html( data );
                        }
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Well, now that we have completed a form to search for users by name and city, we are preparing the code in functions.php

```
// add the ajax fetch js
function users_ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function users_fetch(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'users_data_fetch', username: jQuery('#username').val(), usercountry: jQuery('#usercountry').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#users_list_div').html( data );
        }
    });

}
</script>

<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'users_ajax_fetch' );

function users_data_fetch(){
    if( $_POST['username']){
        if($_POST['usercountry'] != 'all'){
            $user_country = $_POST['usercountry'];
            $compare_country = '=';
        }else{
            $user_country = '';
            $compare_country = 'LIKE';
        }
        
        $args = array(
                    'orderby' => 'first_name',
                    'order'   => 'ASC',
                    'meta_query'    => array(
                        array(
                        'key'      =>  'user_registration_user_country',
                        'value'    =>  $user_country,
                        'compare'      => $compare_country,
                        ),
                        array(
                        'key'      =>  'nickname',
                        'value'    =>  $_POST['username'],
                        'compare'      => 'LIKE',
                        )
                    )

                );
    //}
$users = get_users( $args );
$users_result = $users[0]->ID;
if($users_result){
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
$user_pic = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'profilepicture', true );
$user_type = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'user_registration_user_type', true );

?>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center mb-3">
        <div class="col border pt-2">
            <a href="<?php echo get_site_url() .'/author/'. $user->user_nicename ?>" >
                <? if($user_pic){ ?>
                    <div class="" style="background:url('<?php echo $user_pic ?>');width:110px;height:110px;margin: auto;background-size: cover;background-position: center;    border-radius: 100px;" ></div>
                <?php
                }else{
                        echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/user.svg" style="border-radius:100px;width:110px;height:110px;margin">';
                        //echo get_avatar( $curauth->user_email , '120 '); 
                }
            </a>
            <div class="mt-1 mb-3">
                <?php echo $user->display_name; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <a class="col text-center btn btn-success" href="<?php echo get_site_url() .'/author/'. $user->user_nicename ?>" >
                    <?php echo __('View prfile','booksinfo') ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
}
}else{ ?>
<h5 class="text-center mx-auto mt-3">
    <?php echo __('What you are looking for is not currently found. Please check the case','booksinfo'); ?>
</h5>
<?php }
   }
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_users_data_fetch','users_data_fetch');
    add_action('wp_ajax_users_data_fetch' , 'users_data_fetch');
```

This is the best way I found to do it, here's the example page that I gave
[page link](https://booksreview.info/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B9%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%A1/)